# show category and subcategory in a single select box in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parent-child, dropdownbox

I have a Table Categories with 3 fields
id
name
parent_category_id

Category and subcategory both are store in a same categories table with parent_category_id

example:

id--------------name-------------------parent_category_id

1-------------Category1-------------------nil

2------------ subCategory11----------------1

3------------ subcategory12----------------1

4-------------Catogory2--------------------nil

5--------------subCategory21---------------4

6--------------subCategory22---------------4

Am trying to build a select box from Category Model like this

Select box:

```
category1
    subcategory11
    subcategory12
category2
    subcategory21
    subcategory22
```

User can select category1 or subcategory11

How to make a drop down box like that in Rails3.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `options_for_select` helper method to create custom options for your select fields:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

A recursive method for creating an array, which you can pass to `options_for_select` could look like this:

```
def subcat_prefix(depth)
  ("&nbsp;" * 4 * depth).html_safe
end

def category_options_array(categories=[], parent_id=nil, depth=0)
  Category.where(parent_category_id: parent_id).order(:id).each do |category|
    categories << [subcat_prefix(depth) + category.name, category.id]
    category_options_array(categories, category.id, depth+1)
  end

  categories
end
```

To use the method, for example:

```
select_tag :category_id, options_for_select(category_options_array)
```

Note that this would work for however many levels of subcategories. To alter the look of the select field you can define the `subcat_prefix` method differently or use classes and CSS to style the option tags.

Comment: I got the solution in another way. I use awesome_nested_set
gem for this and its cool :)

Comment: Thanks that was awesome! One less gem and proper answer to the question!

Answer (score 0):

I use "awesome_nested_set" gem for this. Its very smooth to use.

gem 'awesome_nested_set'

If you have already have a categories table with parent_id then add the following 3 columns to your table

```
add_column :categories, :lft, :integer
add_column :categories, :rgt, :integer
add_column :categories, :depth, :integer
```

If you have custom parent(something_parent_id) id instead of parent_id then pass as a option of custom parent_id like:

**acts_as_nested_set  :parent_column => :parent_category_id**

When u want to use as a select box

```
 f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" } 

or

 select_tag 'parent_id', options_for_select(nested_set_options(Category) {|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" } )
```